# Quantum computer simulators

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-information, quantum-computer, software

What are good, free, open source, GUI-based quantum computer simulators?

I remember there used to be a Java-based one that was very good, but it doesn't seem to be online anymore, or it's relocated.

Comment: What do you mean by "quantum computer simulators"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software recommendation.

Comment: Accepted in Stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595156/software-simulation-of-a-quantum-computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of quantum computer simulators, categorized by the programming language in which they were written:

http://www.quantiki.org/wiki/List_of_QC_simulators

Specifically, http://www.davyw.com/quantum/ allows the full simulation of up to 9 qubits.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.