# Quantum computing resource

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, education, quantum-computer

I am a beginner in quantum computing, and I do not have any background in Physics. Can anyone refer me a good material to study the subject?

By assuming quantum mechanics like black box is also making the subject a little complicated, as I cannot understand each and everything completely and I had to memorize a lot without understanding. Like, for instance, I learned the concept of teleportation but that was not very clear to me, as why that concept is great. The postulates I studied, are still unclear and also the circuits are also not becoming very clear. From a computer scientist perspective, that would do I think, but I am not very comfortable, until I understand everything clearly.

Can anyone help me with these issues and suggest me materials to learn the subject more deeply?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2667/

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20260/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60599/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170279/2451